# Geolocator package is not working, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am trying to get the current geolocation in Flutter using the Geolocator package but it's not working.
Here is my function code:

```
local() async {
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;

  var position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

  print(position);
}
```

It's printing NULL.

Note : I have set the proper permissions in AndroidManifest along with the geolocator API key.

Geolocator package version : 5.3.0

Flutter Doctor: (I can't use the last version of flutter currently)

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: on a real device

Comment: i would suggest setting a breakpoint before `getCurrentPosition` and then stepping into the function. This way you might be able to easily find out why it returns null.

Comment: what do you mean by "setting a breakpoint" ??

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the problem with the Geolocator package, so i used the Locator package and it worked fine.

Here's my function :

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';

LocationData locationData;

local() async {
    Location location = new Location();

    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    print(locationData);
  }
```